# Pass data from View to Controller - Surveytype

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a small survey application using mvc. The model goes Questions has an ICollection of answers created by entity framework.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "TakingSurvey";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
ICollection<SurveyAPI.Models.DB.Questions> _questions = ViewBag.questions;
ICollection<SurveyAPI.Models.DB.Answers> _answers = ViewBag.answers;
int i = 0;
foreach (var question in _questions)
{
   <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="@_questions.ElementAt(i).Answers">@_questions.ElementAt(i).QuestionText</label>
          <input asp-for="@_answers.ElementAt(i).AnswerText" class="form-control" />
   </div>
    i++;
}
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
}
```

ViewBag.questions contains the questions. This part works. What I expected to happen was that I'd send an ICollection of answers back to the controller but I'm failing miserably. How can I send a collection of answers (with their respective questionID) to the controller? The answers viewbag is empty objects for each question

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to your form.

```
@using(BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id="anID"}))
```

And then in your javascript you could serialize the form and send it to a controller function such as:

```
$(function(){
    $("#anID").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var x = $("#anID").serializa();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: x,
        success: function(result){
            //whatever
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your controller actions the model of the model passed into the view.